# difficult string to replace in script using SED

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I know, many people have had questions on how to use sed to replace a string, but I have a difficult one here.

I have a file I need to replace a string of text that prompts the user to enter content. I want to automate this so the user does not interact. By replacing this string with a static file path. but the text is a bash script and has ' and " within the string I want to replace. It does not work. Either because I have syntax errors in my formatting, or it simply is not possible to do this action with sed. Please advice!

Here is what I am attempting to do:
I want to replace this long string

```
read -e -p 'Enter path for Boot Partition : '  BOOTUSERFILEPATH
```

with a string that looks like this:

```
BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images
```

My attempt:

```
sed -i "/read -e -p 'Enter path for Boot Partition : '  BOOTUSERFILEPATH/BOOTUSERFILEPATH="../board-support/prebuilt-images"" file_to_search.sh
```

Update: I fixed the syntax error, but file still is not updated with the new path information... :(

found the problem. the search was not finding the strings because of an extra space in my search command. It works now!

Comment: You're missing the `s` command to perform substitution, and you have double quotes inside your quoted string.

Comment: And, since `/` is the delimiter for the `s`, you either need to escape the slashes in the path, or choose different delimiters.

Comment: Do you really need to do this so often that it needs to be automated?

Comment: @ Barmer. Yes we need to automate this because there are 5 questions like this in the script. The script is part of an installer from a supplier, which we can not edit permanently, so I must edit on the fly. Secondly we found that the users keep making typoing these long strings during the install process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are forward slashes in your string so one needs to use a different delmiter. Here I use '|' as the delimiter.

```
sed "s|read -e -p \'Enter path for Boot Partition : \'  BOOTUSERFILEPATH|BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images|g" oldfile > newfile
```

You may note that the `-i` option to sed which allows files to be edited in place is not a POSIX supported option.

However if you wish to use it:

```
sed -i "s|read -e -p \'Enter path for Boot Partition : \'  BOOTUSERFILEPATH|BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images|g" oldfile
```

You may find it easier to use a pattern with `sed` which matches part of this string and then replaces its entirety:

```
sed 's|read -e -p .* BOOTUSERFILEPATH|BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images|g' filename > newfilename
```

From the POSIX specification page for [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> `s/BRE/replacement/flags`
>      Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the pattern space. Any character other than `<backslash>` or `<newline>` can be used instead of a slash to delimit the BRE and the replacement.

Comment: @ Jonathan. This is a great start! thanks! I tried your examples, and it does not error out, however, the output file that got edited is blank! What do you supposed I did wrong here?

Comment: @ Jonathan. OK I tried your first example you gave. It executes without error, creates the "newfile". However the newfile is no different from the old. That input string is still in there. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like you have some variance in your data. try limiting the initial pattern between the three delimiters "|||" ie; "|limit this pattern||"

Comment: yes I should note, this string pattern appears 5 times within the script with only slight variances in the strings. ie. asking the user for different file path input, and assigning the input to a different variable.

Comment: Alright try this:  sed 's|read.*BOOTUSERFILEPATH|BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images|g'  that will match an even greater range of possibilities. Please be careful that this is not changing out other important parts of the program though.

Comment: That 3rd example you give does not work either. If I use the read. *BOOTxxx I get a syntax error. " sed: -e expression #1, char 11: extra characters after command"

Comment: got it figured out. your suggestions were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an actual substitute command, and you need to avoid the slashes in the replacement text from confusing `sed`.  Personally, I'd probably use:

```
sed -i.bak "s%^read .* BOOTUSERFILEPATH$%BOOTUSERFILEPATH=../board-support/prebuilt-images%" file_to_search.sh
```

or even more likely:

```
BOOTUSERFILEPATH="../board-support/prebuild-images"
sed -i.bak "s%^read .* BOOTUSERFILEPATH$%BOOTUSERFILEPATH=$BOOTUSERFILEPATH%" file_to_search.sh
```

The `s%%%` uses `%` instead of `/` to delimit the parts of the command.  I cheated on the match pattern, working on the assumption that you don't have many similar lines in the file.

Comment: Actually, the script that I will be acting upon has 5 instances of this string pattern in it, with only slight variations in the prompt phrase, and the path variable name. so this is why I chose to use the entire string line.

Comment: OK; add the extra characters into the pattern so the right changes are made.